# IndexError: list index out of range when using model.fit

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

When I run the code, the model.fit ends up returning an error saying: IndexError: list index out of range.

Dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11_dvun93KNdK9WrMtNzSB5HDBCgtq8qG/view?usp=sharing

```
# importing and cleaning the data
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import re
import nltk
import string
dataset = pd.read_csv("car_prices.csv")
dataset.pop('vin')
dataset.pop('mmr')
dataset.pop('year')
dataset.pop('odometer')
dataset.pop('condition')
dataset.pop('transmission')
dataset.pop('saledate')
dataset.pop('color')
dataset.pop('interior')
dataset = dataset.dropna(axis=0)
labels = dataset.iloc[:,0:5].values
labels = str(labels)
data = dataset.iloc[:,6].values
print(labels)

MODEL = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/5"
hub_layer = hub.KerasLayer(MODEL, output_shape=[512], input_shape=[1], trainable=True, dtype="string")
model = Sequential()
model.add(hub_layer)
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='SGD', metrics=['accuracy'])
data = np.array(np.array(data))
labels = np.array(np.array(labels))
model.fit(data, labels, epochs=2)
```

Comment: You have set first 5 columns as labels and 6th column as x?Why? And how did you set input shape as 1 and output shape as 512? You are running a regression task and `CategoricalCrossentropy` loss does not make sense. use instead `loss=mse`. Also `metrics=['accuracy']` does not make sense.

Comment: Did you tried as suggested above?

Comment: Yes, I did. It still didn't work. I don't know what to put for metrics though.